# Convert this unicode to string with javascript (Thai Language)

Tags: javascript, unicode, ascii

```
&#xE21;&#xE2D;&#xE40;&#xE15;&#xE2D;&#xE23;&#xE4C;&#xE44;&#xE0B;&#xE04;&#xE4C;
```

Can I convert this unicode to string with JS. (It is Thailand Language)

I use

```
console.log(String.fromCharCode("&#xE21;&#xE2D;&#xE40;&#xE15;&#xE2D;&#xE23;&#xE4C;&#xE44;&#xE0B;&#xE04;&#xE4C;"));
```

And It's not correct. if it right it will show มอเตอร์ไซค์

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Unicode string is encoded using HTML entity notation. Generally that means that whatever encoded the string expected it to end up in the middle of an HTML document, where it would be seen by an HTML parser.

If you've somehow got that string in JavaScript in a browser, you can get to the encoded Unicode by letting the browser parse it:

```js
var str = "&#xE21;&#xE2D;&#xE40;&#xE15;&#xE2D;&#xE23;&#xE4C;&#xE44;&#xE0B;&#xE04;&#xE4C;";
var elem = document.createElement("div");
elem.innerHTML = str;
alert(elem.textContent);
```

The `string.fromCharCode()` function expects one or more *numeric* arguments; it won't understand HTML entities. Thus if you're *not* in a browser (like, if you've got the string in a Node.js program or something like that), you could convert the string with your own code:

```
var str = "&#xE21;&#xE2D;&#xE40;&#xE15;&#xE2D;&#xE23;&#xE4C;&#xE44;&#xE0B;&#xE04;&#xE4C;";
var thai = String.fromCharCode.apply(String, str.match(/x[^;]*;/g).map(function(n) { return parseInt(n.slice(1, -1), 16); }));
```

That conversion will only work when the code points involved are within the first 64K values.

Comment: Note that `.textContent` might not work everywhere; in IE you may have to use `.innerText` instead, at least in older versions.

Answer (score 2):

You may want something like this :

```
var input = "&#xE21;&#xE2D;&#xE40;&#xE15;&#xE2D;&#xE23;&#xE4C;&#xE44;&#xE0B;&#xE04;&#xE4C;";

var output = input.replace(/&#x[0-9A-Fa-f]+;/g,
                           function(htmlCode) {
                               var codePoint = parseInt( htmlCode.slice(3, -1), 16 );
                               return String.fromCharCode( codePoint );
                           });
```

Comment: sorry, I had slipped upon the 16 base in parseInt, needed to edit